# Problems with Looping order

Tags: python, loops, input

I wrote this simple code:

```
alpha=float(input('For the MC Test for the mean define alpha (0.10 and 0.05 only available at the moment): '))
if alpha!=0.05 or alpha!=0.10:
    while True:
        print('Please insert a value equal to 0.05 or 0.10')
        alpha=float(input('For the MC Test for the mean define alpha (0.10 and 0.05 only available at the moment): ')
else:
    print('MC test will control the FWER at exactly {}% (balanced test)'.format(alpha))
```

However it is creating a loop in which even when I type 0.05 it is asking again to insert alpha. I would appreciate your comments. Thanks.

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Plus it cant be both 0.05 and 0.1 so it will always be truthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-arrange your `if` statement to check the proper input first and in `else` statement and the code to read the data again and add a `break` statement once you get the proper input.

```
alpha=float(input('For the MC Test for the mean define alpha (0.10 and 0.05 only available at the moment): '))
if alpha==0.05 or alpha==0.10:
    print('MC test will control the FWER at exactly {}% (balanced test)'.format(alpha))
else:
    while True:
        print('Please insert a value equal to 0.05 or 0.10')
        alpha=float(input('For the MC Test for the mean define alpha (0.10 and 0.05 only available at the moment): ')
        if alpha==0.05 or alpha==0.10:
            print('MC test will control the FWER at exactly {}% (balanced test)'.format(alpha))
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

Just rearrange the loops:

```
while True:
    if alpha not in [0.05,0.1]:
        print('Please insert a value equal to 0.05 or 0.10')
        alpha=float(input('For the MC Test for the mean define alpha (0.10 and 0.05 only available at the moment): '))
    else:
        print('MC test will control the FWER at exactly {}% (balanced test)'.format(alpha))
        break
```